# 'size' on custom product metafield returns '0'

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I'm building a component which checks the character count of a custom product metafield; if it's above 24 characters, the data is output as an accordion, otherwise the metafield content is printed in its entirety. The conditional below fails as the metafield size always returns `0`, but I can see the content printing via the `else` statement so I'm certain the path is valid:

```
{% if product.metafields.custom.product_note.size >= 24 %}
    <div class="product-note has--dropdown">
        <span class="item__heading item__trigger">Product information</span>
        <div class="item__content">
            {{ product.metafields.custom.product_note }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="product-note">
        <div class="item__content">
            {{ product.metafields.custom.product_note }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

I'm not sure it's relevant, but the `product_note` metafield is a multi-line text field. If anyone could point me in the right direction as to why `size` is failing to produce a value, I'd appreciate it massively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try working off the **value** contained in the metafield. It appears you are short-cutting by referring to just the combo of namespace and key, without actually saying: what is the length of the value stored at that namespace and key. Just a thought. You could at least try that.

Comment: Thanks David — never considered that I should just return the value. Appreciate you pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Final answer, courtesy of @David Lazar's suggestion:

```
{% assign data_product_note = product.metafields.custom.product_note.value %}

{% if data_product_note.size >= 24 %}
    <div class="product-note has--dropdown">
        <span class="item__heading item__trigger">Product information</span>
        <div class="item__content">
            {{ data_product_note }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="product-note">
        <div class="item__content">
            {{ data_product_note }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```